# how to get exact value from Y axis and X axix for any point in chart

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, charts

I have a chart with line graph. now for a particular point on the line how can i get the exact co-ordinates from Y axis and/or X axis.
For example if the major unit on Y axis is 200 and Minor unit is 50. How can I get the value from the Y axis for point which lies somewher around 25 or 26 for example? can we do that through normal charts in excel

Comment: If it is a point then just change your chart options to include points and hover over it.  If it is a point that you don't have data for then display the equation of the line and plug in values to that equation

Comment: I'd like to understand your question: When you say "_I have a chart with line graph_" Where is it? Is it in Excel? If yes do you already have the values for X and Y?

Comment: Say for example if you have the values of X and Y between certain intervals and if you would like to interpolate (try to find the values of X & Y - where X and Y are not specified) - Is your line a straight line? If it is a straight line try using the formula Y=m*X+b; where m is the slope of the line and b represents the value where the line passes through the Y axis when X=0